# Python IF and AND statement #value error ( TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

i'm trying to making condition ( if and ) but it keep error me

DF

```
         Segment Out_going Calls
0    Outbound               0
1         nan              10
2    Outbound               0
3    Outbound               0
4    Outbound               0
..        ...             ...
275  Outbound               0
276  Outbound              10
277  Outbound              13
278  Outbound               4
279  Outbound               0
```

i used below code

```
PG["Final_Stuff"]=np.where(PG['Segment'] == 'inbound' & PG['Out_going Calls'] == 0, 0, PG["0"])
```

below is the error appear

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

---

Complete Error

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
    301         #  (xint or xbool) and (yint or bool)
--> 302         result = op(x, y)
    303     except TypeError:

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\roperator.py in rand_(left, right)
     51 def rand_(left, right):
---> 52     return operator.and_(right, left)
     53 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
    315             try:
--> 316                 result = libops.scalar_binop(x, y, op)
    317             except (

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_binop()

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\roperator.py in rand_(left, right)
     51 def rand_(left, right):
---> 52     return operator.and_(right, left)
     53 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14048/3217482720.py in <module>
      1 # if agent have not outbound call or POM then he his trans time will be deduct from FTE
----> 2 PG["Final_Stuff"]=np.where(PG['Segment'] == 'inbound' & PG['Out_going Calls'] == 0, 0, PG["0"])
      3 
      4 #print(PG.head(2))
      5 #PG.to_excel('Test.xlsx' ,index=False)

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __rand__(self, other)
     64     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__rand__")
     65     def __rand__(self, other):
---> 66         return self._logical_method(other, roperator.rand_)
     67 
     68     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__or__")

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _logical_method(self, other, op)
   5511         rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True, extract_range=True)
   5512 
-> 5513         res_values = ops.logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
   5514         return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)
   5515 

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in logical_op(left, right, op)
    390         filler = fill_int if is_self_int_dtype and is_other_int_dtype else fill_bool
    391 
--> 392         res_values = na_logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
    393         # error: Cannot call function of unknown type
    394         res_values = filler(res_values)  # type: ignore[operator]

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
    323             ) as err:
    324                 typ = type(y).__name__
--> 325                 raise TypeError(
    326                     f"Cannot perform '{op.__name__}' with a dtyped [{x.dtype}] array "
    327                     f"and scalar of type [{typ}]"

TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: I don't see an `if` statement anywhere. The error also mentions `rand_`, but that doesn't appear in the code.

Comment: Where is the `Out_going Calls` column in the df?

Comment: i have edit the QA to add the coulm data , regarding IF statment ,i thought that code ( np.where(PG['Segment'] == 'inbound' & PG['Out_going Calls'] == 0 ) can be used as if

Comment: It's similar to an `if` statement because it assigns different values depending on a condition. But it's not really an `if` statement.

Comment: There's still no `rand_` in your code, I don't see how you could be getting that error from it. Post the full traceback.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't know , im new with python , can you support to make if for such df

Comment: You don't need an `if` statement, `np.where()` is the correct way to do this with a dataframe.

Comment: i have added the complete error as appeared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245114/discussion-between-mohamed-khamees-and-barmar).